# Simple jQuery Selectmenu not displaying images in an Angular project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use the [jQuery Selectmenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render) to add images to a dropdown in my `Angular` project.  The following `html` file adapted from the example works fine on it's own when ran in the browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Custom Rendering</title>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
                _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
                    var li = $( "<li>" ),
                        wrapper = $( "<div>", { text: item.label } );

                    if ( item.disabled ) {
                        li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
                    }

                    $( "<span>", {
                        style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
                        "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
                    })
                        .appendTo( wrapper );

                    return li.append( wrapper ).appendTo( ul );
                }
            });

            $( "#people" )
                .iconselectmenu()
                .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget")
                    .addClass( "ui-menu-icons avatar" );
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Selectmenu with custom avatar 16x16 images as CSS background</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="people">Select a Person:</label>
        <select name="people" id="people">
            <option value="1" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">John Resig</option>
            <option value="2" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Tauren Mills</option>
            <option value="3" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Jane Doe</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

I see this:

[image]

However, when I add it to my `Angular` project I just see a plain dropdown with no images:

[image]

**EDIT**:

I think I forgot to clear the cache.  I see something:

[image]

Perhaps it's a styling issue.

My Controller:

```
Fasttrack.controller('TasksCtrl', function ($scope, TasksService, TimetrackService, Salesmen, SweetAlert,
SelectedUser, HoursService, $http, $filter, Salescalls) {

  $( function() {
        $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
            _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
                var li = $( "<li>" ),
                    wrapper = $( "<div>", { text: item.label } );

                if ( item.disabled ) {
                    li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
                }

                $( "<span>", {
                    style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
                    "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
                })
                    .appendTo( wrapper );

                return li.append( wrapper ).appendTo( ul );
            }
        });

        $( "#people" )
            .iconselectmenu()
            .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget")
                .addClass( "ui-menu-icons avatar" );
    } );
etc.......
```

No resources are missing.  Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please supply your angular code and how you're adding this component to the angular project. (otherwise we'll need to guess) For the time being. In the earlier versions of angular you would have needed to use something called a `directive`, but as of the later versions the `component` concept was introduced. Try searching online with for those in conjunction with jQuery and you'll find ample examples.

Comment: @RohanBüchner Thanks.  Yes, I edited the question.

Comment: Your code is working. There must be another think we dont know..

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız Thank you, yes, I tried the code in a dummy Angular project I have and all is well.  I guess the problem is some styling issue.